# ScalaFX TableView - simple example compiler error

Tags: scala, scalafx

I am just trying to get familiar with ScalaFX, and my Scala knowledge is also still in embryo phase. Can you please help me out, in the following simple problem?

```
import scalafx.application.JFXApp
import scalafx.application.JFXApp.PrimaryStage
import scalafx.collections.ObservableBuffer
import scalafx.scene.Scene
import scalafx.scene.control.TableColumn._
import scalafx.scene.control.{TableCell, TableColumn, TableView}

object Gui extends JFXApp {

case class listInfo(text: String, subtexts: List[String], thumbnail: String, attributeField: Int)

  val demo = ObservableBuffer[listInfo](
    new listInfo("dewdfasc", subtexts = List("first", "second"), "tdsam", 1),
    new listInfo("hgfhfghn", subtexts = List("first", "second"), "tdsacdsm", 2)
  )

  stage = new PrimaryStage {
    title = "ScalaFX Hello World"
    scene = new Scene {
      root = TableView[listInfo](demo) {
        columns ++= List(
          new TableColumn[listInfo, String] {
            text = "band"
            cellValueFactory = {_.value.text}
            prefWidth = 100
          },
          new TableColumn[listInfo, String] {
            text = "thumbnail"
            cellValueFactory = {_.value.thumbnail}
            prefWidth = 100
          }
        )
      }
    }
  }

}
```

has the following compiler error:

```
Error:(20, 23) object TableView does not take type parameters.
      root = TableView[listInfo](demo) {
Error:(21, 9) not found: value columns
        columns ++= List(
Error:(24, 41) type mismatch;
 found   : String
 required: scalafx.beans.value.ObservableValue[String,String]
            cellValueFactory = {_.value.text}
Error:(29, 41) type mismatch;
 found   : String
 required: scalafx.beans.value.ObservableValue[String,String]
            cellValueFactory = {_.value.thumbnail}
```

my environment:

java 1.8

scala 2.12

scalafx 2.11-8.0.144-R12

What should I correct, so that it compiles?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
import scalafx.application.JFXApp
import scalafx.beans.property.StringProperty
import scalafx.collections.ObservableBuffer
import scalafx.scene.Scene
import scalafx.scene.control.TableColumn._
import scalafx.scene.control.{ TableColumn, TableView }

object Gui extends JFXApp {
    case class ListInfo(_text: String, _subtexts: List[String], _thumbnail: String, _attributeField: Int) {
        val text = new StringProperty(this, "text", _text)
        val thumbnail = new StringProperty(this, "thumbnail", _thumbnail)
    }

    val demo = ObservableBuffer[ListInfo](
        ListInfo("dewdfasc", List("first", "second"), "tdsam", 1),
        ListInfo("hgfhfghn", List("first", "second"), "tdsacdsm", 2)
    )

    stage = new JFXApp.PrimaryStage {
        title.value = "ScalaFX Hello World"
        scene = new Scene {
            root = new TableView[ListInfo](demo) {
                columns ++= List(
                    new TableColumn[ListInfo, String] {
                        text = "band"
                         cellValueFactory = _.value.text
                         prefWidth = 100
                    },
                    new TableColumn[ListInfo, String] {
                        text = "thumbnail"
                        cellValueFactory = _.value.thumbnail
                        prefWidth = 100
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- Use uppercased types(e.g. ListInfo)
- New keyboard is redundant when creating instanse of case class
- cellValueFactory expecting scalafx.beans.value.ObservableValue[String,String] instead of string(see case class ListInfo val's)

Comment: After doing the adjustments you proposed, I still get 2 compiler error:
Error:(26, 23) object TableView does not take type parameters.
      root = TableView[ListInfo](demo) {
Error:(27, 9) not found: value columns
        columns ++= List(

Is there an import missing?

Comment: I was also using the same imports.

Comment: Could you check your scalafx versioned at 8.0.144-R12?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm, it is 8.0.144-R12.

Comment: I have noticed you are using scala 2.12 but scalafx 2.11-8.0.144-R12 maybe the missmatch happens there?

scalaVersion := "2.12.5"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalafx" %% "scalafx" % "8.0.144-R12"

this is my sbt  configurations.

Comment: Just tried with scala versions 2.11.8 and 2.12.4, and I get the same compile error in both cases.

Comment: update scalafx 2.11-8.0.144-R12 to scalafx 2.12-8.0.144-R12 maybe that could help.